# Design tips for a limited run-time motor circuit

Tags: dc-motor, timer

I'm building a small 'explosion simulator' for my son's trench warfare diorama. I'm going to have a pushbutton momentary switch, a white LED, and a small hobby motor with an asymmetrical load, so that it rumbles. That's all fine, but I'd like to have only a sec or two of the rumbling and the light per button press (even if the button is held).

What's the best way to make the circuit operate for only a short time? I haven't had luck with adding a capacitor in series (as it charges, it reduces the voltage across the LED and the motor, causing them to stop). Other ideas?

Comment: Why not just require whoever holds the button to hold it for the time that seems about right for the rumble.  This is a one-off.  No need to get fancy and automated.

Comment: Well, it's a kid, and I think it'd be fun to have the explosion be a little more automated. Also, 'cause I get to learn how to do it that way :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need a non retriggerable monostable: -

[image]

[image]

Picture taken from and explanation provided by [this](http://en.f-alpha.net/electronics/integrated-circuits/timer-555/go-on/experiment-12-non-retriggerable-monoflop/) website.

You need to add to this a MOSFET for driving the motor and you should be done: -

[image]

Choose a logic level MOSFET.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would probably be a relay controlled by a timer. It's easy to build one, but I'd bet they sell them as ready-to-use modules.

**EDIT:**

Someone else has provided you with an excellent schematic for building your own circuit, which I recommend if you want to have some DIY fun. :) Otherwise look for commercially available modules like this one:

[Timer+relay with monostable operation.](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/LED-Display-Digital-Delay-Timer-High-Performance-Timer-Relay-Module-Automation-Control-Relay-Switch-Module-3V/32627458786.html?spm=2114.01010208.8.59.pINAQG)

[image: Timer+relay with monostable operation]

Comment: Thanks for the link and the answer - I would love to pick both here, but I went with the DIY approach.